# Image upload issue in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on image upload in CodeIgniter. In this regard I am using following code.

```
$config['upload_path'] = './files/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
      $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
      echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'message'=>$error)); //this line is not working.
}
else
{
      echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>lang('items_successful_updating').' '. $item_data['name'],'item_id'=>$item_id));
}
```

If I use below code then it is working.

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'message'=>'abcdef'));
```

Why it is happening so?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: Try this :
echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'message'=>$error['error']));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->upload->display_errors();` returns error array with error code and error message etc. Json Encoding may cause issue sometime in case of multidimensional array. you can use error message only, what I guess from you coding structure.

Correct Way is:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './files/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
      $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
      echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'message'=>$error['error'])); //this line is not working.
}
else
{
      echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>lang('items_successful_updating').' '. $item_data['name'],'item_id'=>$item_id));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bikram Pahi. After using your code I am getting error `&lt;`. What does it mean ?

Comment: &lt; used for ( < ) , please check in your IDE you will get if any typo error or  left php tags etc.